# How to change <html lang="bg-BG" , but only for one page

Tags: php, multi-language

I spent last 4 hours searching for an answer how to change html lang="bg-BG"  to html lang="en-GB". I already reviewed the old topics, and it seems that define ('WPLANG', 'xx_XX'); is not working anymore, after Wordpress v4 release.

The web site has multiple pages and post written in bg-BG, but now the client needs just a single en-GB page to present his services. The page is already prepared for the public, but I want to change the html lang to the correct language. I already managed to change the og to be

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB"/>
```

with this

```
add_filter('wpseo_locale', 'override_og_locale');
function override_og_locale($locale)

{
    if ( is_page( 2846) ) {
        return "en_GB";

    }
    else {
        return "bg_BG";
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what php function do I need? I think it will be an overkill to use a plugin just for a single page...

Comment: See filter `'language_attributes'` in `get_language_attributes()` function in "../../../wp-includes/general-template.php".

Answer (score 3):

You should hook with the `locale` filter:

```
add_filter('locale', 'my_get_locale');

function my_get_locale($locale) {

    if ( is_page( 2846) ) {

        return "en_GB";

    }

    return $locale;
}
```